# someone wanting to study

Tags: grammar, gerunds

> someone wanting to study

I want to ask how do you call this structure or why do we use a **wanting** here?

We can definitely rephrase it as *someone who wants to study how*, but anyway, why is the word **wanting** here?

Apart from this I'm giving you an example sentence:

> *"He also troubleshoots matters pertaining to industrial unrest."*

are they used similarly? like pertaining and wanting? were they complement here?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very difficult to understand. I appreciate that English is not your first language (otherwise you would not be here) but if we can't understand the question we cannot answer it. Could you perhaps provide a **full quotation** from your source material, and then *separately* explain what you do not understand?

Comment: @ Astralbee i wanted to ask why do we use " wanting" in the sentence "someone wanting to study", what was the function of wanting

Answer (score 1):

Both "wanting" and "pertaining" are participles.  The Engish present participle is 
has the form "verb-ing".

Participles can be used to modify or describe nouns, rather like adjectives.

> Wanting to go home, The girl walked out of school.

In this sentence there is a participle clause. The implied subject is "the girl"

Relative clauses can also be used to modify or describe nouns

> The girl, who wanted to go home, walked out of school.

And like relative clauses, a particle can come after the noun.

> The girl, wanting to go home, walked out of school.

A participle can be used instead of a relative clause, and this is the structure that is being used in your two examples.